# Populate DataGrid through Button Command

Tags: xaml, binding, viewmodel, itemssource

TheContext refers to my ViewModel in the resources section

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource TheContext}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}">
```

This is my viewModel.cs

```
public CarsSearchResultsViewModel()
{
     ButtonCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => GetCars());
}

public void GetCars()
{
     List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
     cars.Add(new Car() { Make = "Chevy", Model = "Silverado" });
     cars.Add(new Car() { Make = "Honda", Model = "Accord" });
     cars.Add(new Car() { Make = "Mitsubishi", Model = "Galant" });
     Cars = new ObservableCollection<Car>(cars);
}

private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars;
public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
{
     get { return _cars; }
     private set
     {
         if (_cars == value) return;
         _cars = value;
     }
}
```

I have tried adding `OnPropertyChanged("Cars")`, I have tried adding adding `People = null` before adding the list, I have tried adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the ItemsSource, and before using ObservableCollection I tried using `IViewCollection`.

Im not trying to update or delete from a collection, just populate the grid with a button click. If i run `GetCars()` in the constructor without the command it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel needs to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanges` interface, and call `OnpropertyChanged` in the setter of your `ObservableCollection` so that when you reinstated the UI will get notified so you Cars property should looks somethink like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars ;
    public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
    {
        get
        {
            return _cars;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_cars == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _cars = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

The Cars collection needs to be defined inside **TheContext** class since it is your Context and that last one needs to implement the mentioned interface :

```
public  class TheContext:INotifyPropertyChanged
{


    //Cars property and your code ..

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: besides that you might reconsider using the context as a static resource unless there are a need for that !?

Comment: Thanks. It definitely had to do with the context. I wasnt declaring in the scope of my button. I moved the context around and it works. why its static? dont know just dont like code in the .cs file its my first app in wpf

Comment: Okay  then, i suggest that you take a look into the mvvm pattern and try to build all your future projects around it, Good luck ;)
accept the answer if it did help you.